# Refresh content of html file inside an uiwebview (iphone)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, uiwebview

I loading a simple html file inside the UIWebView. This html contains a single image of a Webcam.

```
<img id="image" src="http://server.tld/lastwebcamimage.jpg" width="300" height="245" />
```

Now I want to refresh this htmlfile/image **every 6 seconds**, and display the updated webcam image.

I tried:

```
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="cache-control">
<meta content="no-cache" http-equiv="pragma">
<meta content="6" http-equiv="refresh">
```

AND

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var active = window.setInterval("reloadMe()", 6000);
    function reloadMe() {
        window.location.reload()
    }
</script>
```

but **it doenst work**. Any other knows ways to refresh the page?

Thx.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Schedule an `NSTimer` to fire every 6 seconds and call `-[UIWebView reload]`.

Comment: This is the best way to go about things, unless he has other content around it that he doesn't want to refresh. Though there isn't much space on an iPhone screen, so he might want to reconsider if that's the case.